# What system privilege is needed for a user to manage user accounts only

Tags: security, oracle-12c, users

I'm looking to delegate user termination to our NOC.

Requirements are:

1. A user NOC will be created
2. User NOC will execute stored procedures allowing them to either 1) lock another db account or 2) Modify a db account.
3. NOC should not be able to run alter user statements without using the stored procedures.

Answer (score 3):

Create the procedures with `AUTHID DEFINER` option (this is the default if you skip this clause) in a schema who has the `ALTER USER` privilege.

Them simply grant execute on these procedures to NOC.

NOC does not need any other privileges, as the procedures will run as if their owner would have called them.